# SSIS and IIS in different Server and trying to implement SSIS in ASP.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm relatively new to SSIS so please go easy on me. We have 2 production server,one is for database and other one is for IIS. We are planning to develop SSIS package and going to implement it in the .net environment.
So we can manually upload the excel,csv spreadsheet and load in to our database.
We are using SQL-server 2008R2. Is it possible to do it?

I googled and found out that you can do if you installed SSIS service in your IIS server too.
Is there any way we can do it without installing SSIS service in IIS server?

How about using stored procedure to execute it? If so, Can we pass excel file path which is in IIS server? Can you please provide me some useful links?

Please give me you thoughts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you push files to database server using .net to a shared secured location and then poll folder using SSIS for new files and upload data from file if new file is found?

Comment: Thanks, I don't think DBA will agree with it :( . So no other way?

Comment: I think this article on SSIS and web services might be helpful to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx I've accessed SSRS via web services to render Excel sheets but I haven't tried the method with SSIS described in the article.

Comment: Thanks, I ll try that method. I doubt that i can pass file names as parameters.